# need help connecting ms access to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need help my program don't the use connection string that i want instead it find the access file on this folder and display error
Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Patientt\Patientt\bin\Debug\db_hospital.accdb'.

here is my code

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db_hospital.accdb"
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPatients"
    ds.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
```

Comment: where is your accdb file stored ? In your Data Directory or debug folder ?

Comment: here is the path:C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Patientt\Patientt

Comment: it is in the data directory

Comment: App_Data this is the data directory as far as i know

Comment: i copy the connection string from the connection wizard

Answer (score 0):

Put your access file in the debug folder and change the connection string like this

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db_hospital.accdb"
```

Comment: Putting the file on debug folder will open the connection. But my problem is why it doesn't use the connection string